# Using Custom Zend Application Classes from outside

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to use a custom developed class (within Zend Application) from outside a simple php file.

Like a class ABC (in Zend) i want to use it from outside the zend application like from (some_independent_file.php).

I actually want to write cron jobs and use some methods from my custom developed zend classes which are further dependent on zend classes.

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Help on what? Do you need some courage? You can do it Andrew!

Comment: LOL; in short what i want to do is; can i load my entire zend application to some outside php class so if i am doing new SomeClass() it gets there; now its giving me error that cannot find class. I know i can do include but that wont help either can classes are dependednt on each other and further to zend library.

Answer (score 2):

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';


$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

//Now here you can use Zend framework any component as you like to use for your cron to work
```